# Как "растянуть" пиксели в QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene

Делаю небольшой графический редактор на QGraphicsView размером 30х30 и сейчас моя сцена выглядит так (рис. 1)

[image: Рис. 1]

Размер сцены 300х300. А мне нужна сцена размером 30х30 пикселей но, что бы пиксели были "промасштабированые" как на рис. 2

[image: Рис. 2]

Пожалуйста подскажите как так сделать. Спасибо.

Comment: Я не помню как нужные функции назоваются, так что смотрите scale. Ну или можно вручную оперировать элементами матрицы m00 и m11